# Autocomplete function not working in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an autocomplete textbox function which I am using in meteor.
It works fine for the following hardcoded data like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
        $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput(                    
          [{id: 7,  name: "Ruby"},{id: 11, name: "Python"},{id: 13, name: "JavaScript"}],
          {theme: "facebook"}
        );
});
```

Now , I had fetched data from database MongoDB, when I pass this data as parameter to the autocomplete function it does not work... I have also used the method `JSON.stringify()`.

The returned data looks like :

```
[{"_id":"ab170916-a44b-49f9-85ef-a34c90fb815d","Namelist_name":"Badminton"},
 {"_id":"f768e4ba-b628-4d3f-8da6-0bad31346dcc","Namelist_name":"Biking"},
 {"_id":"0bee086b-1785-40c9-9c5d-a39331c875e1","Namelist_name":"Chess"},
 {"_id":"4eae1e54-ec60-4578-8052-0bf1bccf13b1","Namelist_name":"Golf"},
 {"_id":"a0d2b89e-a2d6-4b30-8e38-779c5a886d49","Namelist_name":"Hiking"},
 {"_id":"f3a05456-38d4-40f2-86b1-eddea061fdf0","Namelist_name":"Tennis"},
 {"_id":"3669b9a2-3f87-4579-8064-82d627196fcb","Namelist_name":"Walking"},
 {"_id":"6ac6497e-82b2-40fe-8b24-152e9f42750d","Namelist_name":"Wine Tasting"},
 {"_id":"15a7ca87-aef7-43ab-945b-168647bb59aa","Namelist_name":"Yoga"},
 {"_id":"bc40d166-64ef-4e61-85cd-60064dc037cd","Namelist_name":"Zumba"}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you correctly, but `JSON.stringify()` serializes your js object into a JSON string, so maybe that's not what you want actually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the Namelist_name with only name keyword. Since jquery tokeninput uses name as key 
as mentioned in your hardcoded data. And if we download jquery tokeninput from http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/. we come to know that the keyword is 'name'.

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 1):

If you compare your returned JSON data with the test data that works there is one essential difference: you are missing the `id` field in your MongoDB JSON results and instead providing `_id`.  The `id` field is currently a hardcoded default for the [jQuery tokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin you are using for autocomplete.

Several folks have submitted patches to allow setting a different key using the [tokenValue](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/search?q=tokenValue) parameter.

Example (untested) patch: [tokenValue cannot be changed](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/171).

Answer (score 1):

If you're autocompleting multiple items with free text, you may want to check out this package I created:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete